# Hot to "flatten" an ObjectProperty of an ObjectProperty in TornadoFX (JavaFX extension)?

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

Let's say I have three classes:

```
class A {
    val bProperty: ObjectProperty<B> = SimpleObjectProperty(B(C("test")))

    val cObservable: ObservableValue<C> = ???
}

class B(initialC: C) {
    val cProperty: ObjectProperty<C> = SimpleObjectProperty(initialC)
}

class C(val string: String)
```

As you may have seen, in class A I want to have a **`cObservable`**, which updates its value either when the value of `bProperty` changed or when the value of `cProperty` in the current `bProperty.value` changed.

The closest I got to was something like this:

```
val cObservable: ObservableValue<ObjectProperty<C>> = nonNullObjectBinding(bProperty) {
        value.cProperty
    }
```

But this gives me an `ObservableValue` of an `ObservableValue` of `C` and not an **`ObservableValue` of `C`**. So this is nothing I can work with.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `select` extension method:

```
val cObservable: ObservableValue<C> = bProperty.select { it.cProperty }
```

or:

```
val cObservable: ObservableValue<C> = bProperty.select (B::cProperty)
```